# How to format chapter headings like section headings with no pagebreak and in twocolumn mode

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, titlesec

I looked into a dozen threads on how to get chapters to not produce a new page. None of the solutions worked for me. For instance, [this solution](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2521), produces an error when two chapters occur on the same page and produces nonsense output when used with `twocolumn`, where the text from an earlier chapter is rendered under the subsequent chapter:

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   
    twocolumn
]{scrreprt}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % defines file's character encoding
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\par%
   \thispagestyle{plain}%
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}{%
\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{bla}

CHAPTER TEXT BEGINS HERE.
\lipsum[100]

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get chapter headings behave just like section headings? No page breaks and playing nice with two column documents.

Comment: Do you absolutely ant to stick  ti `scrreprt`? The `komascript` classes should not be used with `\titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard Ok, I get the same issues with for example the normal book class as well though.

Comment: Do you want  chapter headings to be full text width, or column width?

Comment: @Bernard Column width, just like sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have, with `titlesec` to change the class of `chapter` from `top` to `straight`. I took the opportunity to simplify the code with titlesec relevant options, and the simplified syntax for `\titlespacing` (*3.5 means 3.5ex with some stretchability and a minute shrinkability, according to the documentation, p.5).

Here is a code and result for the book class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{book}%
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % defines file's character encoding
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{%
\thispagestyle{plain}\filcenter\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{*3.5}{*2.3}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bla}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Blabla}

CHAPTER TEXT BEGINS HERE.
\lipsum[100]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. This works with the scrreport class too, as I tested. Am I overlooking something there, since you said these should normally not be used together?

Comment: I don't use komascript myself, but that's what is said  regularly on this site, so you have to be careful.

Comment: @lotolmencre While this suggestion works with KOMA-Script version 3.26b (current), you will get error message with the next KOMA-Script version (3.27). See https://komascript.de/releasesvn (German).

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion without package `titlesec` (do not use this package with a KOMA-Script class):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{scrreprt}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % defines file's character encoding
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries,
  style=section
]{chapter}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{\raggedchapter\thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}}{}%
  \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Bla}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Blabla}
CHAPTER TEXT BEGINS HERE.
\lipsum[100]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does not compile for me. Throws `main.tex, line 9
Class scrreprt Error: section indent of \chapter unknown.` for line `]{chapter}`

Comment: If you are using KOMA-Script Version 3.23 or older, then add `indent=0pt` to the settings for chapters: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[ ... ,indent=0pt]{chapter}`. Current version in the distributions (and on CTAN) is 3.26b.